# Why issues occured while i use the same VM image for domain controller and for other machines?

Tags: active-directory, domain, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

We have hosted an Windows 2008 R2 server image in VMware ESXi and made it as domain controller.

We have used the same image for many other machines. When we try to add those machines into domain , we are facing issue while adding domainusers in administrator group.

Whether any uniqueness has to be maintained for Domain controller?

If so What shall be the remedy? Should i use separate image for other machines or some other easy way to make domain controller as unique?

Answer (score 4):

When a machine is used to create a new domain, its local SID is used as the domain SID.

When the SID of the domain accounts matches the SID of local accounts, as it will when your domain's SID is identical to the local machine SID, things will break.

At the very least, run sysprep on cloned machines before making new domains with them.